# Theorem on Giuga number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Giuga number : $n$ is a Giuga number  $\iff$ For every prime factor $p$ of $n$ , $p | (\frac{n}{p}-1)$

How to prove the following theorem on Giuga numbers

$n$ is a giuga number $\iff$ $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^{\phi(n)} \equiv -1 \mod {n} $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $\Rightarrow$ part.
For first, a giuga number must be squarefree, since, by assuming $p^2\mid n$, we have that $p$ divides two consecutive numbers, $\frac{n}{p}$ and $\frac{n}{p}-1$, that is clearly impossible. So we have: 
$$ n = \prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i $$
that implies:
$$ \phi(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} (p_i-1).$$ By considering the sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^{\phi(n)}$$
$\pmod{p_i}$ we have that all the terms contribute with a $1$, except the multiples of $p_i$ that contribute with a zero. This gives:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^{\phi(n)}\equiv n-\frac{n}{p_i}\equiv (n-1)\pmod{p_i}\tag{1}$$
that holds for any $i\in[1,k]$. The chinese theorem now give:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^{\phi(n)}\equiv n-1\pmod{\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i}$$
that is just:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^{\phi(n)}\equiv -1\pmod{n}$$
as claimed. For the $\Leftarrow$ part, we have that the congruence $\!\!\!\pmod{n}$ implies the congruence $\!\!\!\pmod{p_i}$, hence $(1)$ must hold, so we must have:
$$\frac{n}{p_i}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$$
that is equivalent to $p_i\mid\left(\frac{n}{p_i}-1\right).$